# Mysql server not starting in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am getting the following error when i start the mysql server from xampp control panel

MySQL Service detected with wrong path

```
PM 03:06:44  [mysql]    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
PM 03:06:44  [mysql]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
PM 03:06:44  [mysql]    Found Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf mysql
PM 03:06:44  [mysql]    Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
PM 03:06:44  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
```

Comment: You have tried to Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or Uninstall/disable the other service manually, haven't you?

Comment: sorry didnt get you, I just installed xampp and now i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I ran Xampp as administrator.Uninstalled the Mysql. And now every is running fine .

But now i can access the localhost:1234 as port for my Apache is 1234